# Log file is not being written in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, logging, monolog

I have logging enabled by default on Laravel 5.5.

The settings are:

In `config/app.php` file:

```
'log' => env('APP_LOG', 'single'),

'log_level' => env('APP_LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
```

In `.env` file:

```
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
```

If any error happens on the application, I can see the exception page. But I don't see it in the log file anymore. It was working fine a couple of months ago. Even when I try to log manually, it does not log it.

```
Log::debug('Notification');
```

I have code to create files using `Storage` and it's working fine. So, I don't think it's some permission issue. What could be the reason behind this?

Comment: try `php artisan config:clear && php artisan optimize`

Comment: @TsaiKoga No, it does not help.

Comment: What's the content of `$request` ?

Comment: @apokryfos It could be anything. That's written as an example. Even when I encounter fatal errors, it does not log though it shows the exception on the screen.

Comment: In order to not get an `Array to string` errror it can't really be anything. It should be a string or convertible to a string. There's special handling for the case `[ 'exception' => $exception ]` where you can pass an exception in that key. This is unless you're using a custom log handler.

Comment: @apokryfos Thank you for explaining it. But even simple logging without contextual data does not work.

Comment: coud you do
`php artisan tinker` and then `config('logging')` this way you get a dump of your PARSED logging configuration.

And you can be sure what settings the logger is using, regardless of env files, and env vars, etc.

Comment: Futhermore, did you change the exceptionhandler in the application ever?
or did you do any framework upgrades?

Comment: @DannyEbbers That's a good suggestion, but I don't think there is any such thing as `config('logging')`. It could be `config('app.log')` or `config('app.log_level')`. These settings are correct.

Comment: @DannyEbbers No, I did not change the exceptionhandler. The app was upgraded to Laravel 5.5 more than a year ago. Logging seems to be stopped working a couple of months ago.

Comment: You are right it's logging since, laravel 5.6. I forgot that it has been moved in the past. However your suggestion should do the trick.

To make sure its not a permission issue, you could try to do a manual fopen() and fwrite() from tinker, to see if it has permission

Or just create the file from you editor and chmod it a+rw , to ensure it's writeable
(However consider, a+rw is not a production grade permission setting)

Comment: What you could also try from tinker is getting the instance of the actual logger
`$logger = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::getLogger();``
then print it `print_r($logger);`

You should be able to see the expected log file somewhere in the object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the issue. I am using Bugsnag (for production) and I had set it up in the project.

When I integrated it, I used the instruction it had on its dashboard, which I believe was not complete as they have it on their [documentation](https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/php/laravel/#laravel-5-0-5-5). So, I had added the following code in the register method of my application service provider app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php.

```
$this->app->alias('bugsnag.logger', \Illuminate\Contracts\Logging\Log::class);
$this->app->alias('bugsnag.logger', \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class);
```

In my local environment, I had not set the `BUGSNAG_API_KEY` in my `.env` file. So, it was neither sending the exceptions to Bugsnag nor logging into the local laravel.log file.

When I was integrating Bugsnag to another project which runs on Laravel 6, I suspected this issue and checked the documentation. There I found the code which is needed to keep logging to my original logger as well as Bugsnag.

```
$this->app->alias('bugsnag.multi', \Illuminate\Contracts\Logging\Log::class);
$this->app->alias('bugsnag.multi', \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
php artisan config:cache
```

If the issue is related to laravel application cache, then the artisan command will help to cache all your config files ( with current changes ) into a single file. In laravel the config values are obtain from the application cache, so you've to run this command whenever you change the config files. To update the application cache with the latest changes.

If the issue is not related to application cache, you can track the real cause using the apache2 error logs.

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Answer (score 2):

May you have accidentally changed default log path or anything in the configuration array

```
'single' => [
    'driver' => 'single',
    'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
    'level' => 'debug',
],
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be you have given permission and ownership to storage folder not insider folders like: taking case on redhat, because in case of redhat apache user is apache and in case of debian or most other www-data

```
folder | Permission | ownership 
storage | 775 | root:apache 
storage/logs | 755 | root:apache
storage/logs | 775 | root:root
```

It should be minimum

```
storage/logs | 775 | root:apache
or 
storage/logs | 755 | apache:apache
```

and please check once with 
APP_DEBUG=true

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that your log level is set to debug, and remember to clear your config cache after changing that value

```
.env file 
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug

run in console
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 0):

So two things here:

1. Double-check if you definitely have the below on your `.env` file, 
   basically checking to see if it's not a falsey value.:

```
APP_LOG=daily
```

2. Make sure your `storage` directory is writable to the server user:

```
chmod -R 755 storage
```

Answer (score 0):

change the file permission to 777 and if the errors exist in log file it is for permission . you can check the user run php using :

ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'

and correct the file permission .

if the problem is not for permission then you can use error_get_last() after the code lines you write in the log file and see what is the error.

if you don't have error maybe the address of write log file in config is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

**if previously the logging was ok, and you see wrong encoded stringsg**

then its easy to fix.
Clear log file and in dropup list in very bottom-right(mine was UTF-16LE)  pickup **utf-8** encoding .
Hit on *convert* button (in the arisen popup dialog with three buttons)
and also further you can use:

```
echo "" > storage/logs/laravel.log
```